# C to C# (accessing C DLL callback function from C#)

Tags: c#, c++, dll, callback

I would like to get some support how to convert C the code below to C#. 
I have a DLL in C, which has certain functions, I could convert the DLL calls, but the functionality  has one callback declaration and I could not convert this C code to C#.

**This is the callback declaration in C looks like this:**

```
typedef int(*FunctionPointer)(PTCallBackStructure TCallbackRecord, 
BSTR MessageFromDLL, BSTR &MessageToDLL);
```

**this is the callback function itlself in the C code - this is actually called from the DLL:**

```
int test_DLL_Callback(PTCallBackStructure TCallbackRecord, BSTR MessageFromDLL, 
BSTR   &MessageToDLL)
{
 ....
 return 0;
}
```

**This is the code, how the DLL functions is passed to the DLL:**
    DLL_Callback = test_DLL_Callback;

```
PDllCommands = (DllCommands*)malloc((sizeof(DllCommands)));
PDllCommands->CallbackFunction = DLL_Callback;
...
```

Structure PDLLCommands has one item for the callback function, this structire is passed over to the DLL. On the proceeding test_DLL_Callback is called in the C code from the DLL.

I hope now I could clarify what my problems is. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: described above. I would like to have this code in C#, especially the callback related part.

Comment: I don't think questions about translating are off-topic, but I'm voting to close because just asking people to translate a long piece of code for you doesn't really fit with SO.

Comment: I have made my question more concrete, however I think others are putting much longer code snippets. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Creating function pointers from delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261459%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Take note (that is mentioned there), that the delegate must be alive until the callback, but the GC would collect it if you won't keep reference to it.

Comment: thanks, but how the solution would like based on the code snipet I copied above ?

Comment: You should create a delegate with signature compatible with the C function pointer. That includes creating binary-compatible types for the ones used in C. Then create delegate instance for that delegate, and creating function pointer from it.